# Identify raster pixel value using ArcGIS Portal Map Viewer

Tags: raster, arcgis-portal, arcgis-10.7, arcgis-image-server

I have a raster I've published to ArcGIS Image Server 10.5.1. I'm trying to create a web map in 10.7.1 Portal where I can query the pixel value. Ideally the user can click on the raster and a popup will display the pixel value.

Is this functionality possible?

I tried publishing my raster as a Tiled Map Service and an Image Service with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with Esri, we determined that this functionality is not possible across different versions of ArcGIS. In this case an Image service published to ArcGIS Image Server 10.5.1 will not work correctly in Portal 10.7.1. I tested publishing to Image Server 10.7.1 and everything worked correctly.